# Calling C from Java8 using JNA via cygwin

Tags: java, c, cygwin, jna

Reproducing the instructions at
    http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna
for calling C code from java I have:

```
/* ctest.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void helloFromC()
{   
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

This is compiled into the library using:
    gcc -o libctest.so -shared ctest.c

Then Java calling program is:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public interface CTest extends Library
    {
        public void helloFromC();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);

        ctest.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

Then the java is compiled in Java8 using the -cp classpath argument:

```
javac HelloWorld.java -cp jna.jar
```

This step works, producing two class files, HelloWorld.class and HelloWorld$1.class.

The execute step does not work:

```
java HelloWorld -cp jna.jar
```

instead producing the following output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Library
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Library
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
```

The output is effectively identical to: [JNA example program java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773720/jna-example-program-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) which I have carefully reviewed.

I have run many tests of java8 under cygwin and they all work, this one does not.
I have constructed many permutations of this example, including creating the sun.com.jna directories and including HelloWorld in the package. I have also used different delimiters which are necessary in some circumstances. All of them fail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't set your classpath. `NoClassDefFoundError`indicates that your `ClassLoader`can't find your compiled classes.