# Java YoutubePlayer in Swing

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video straight to the JFrame in IntelliJ.
I add the following libraries: DJNativeSwing.jar, DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar and swt.jar. I have to compile THREE .jar files.

[image: libraries]

YoutubePlayer_Swing.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NativeInterface.open();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("YouTube Viewer");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(800, 600);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();
    // don't forget to properly close native components
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NativeInterface.close();
        }
    }));
}

public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
    webBrowser.navigate("https://www.youtube.com/v/b-Cr0EWwaTk?fs=");
    return webBrowserPanel;
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Native
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.getHandle(SWTNativeComponent.java:948)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.createNativePeer(SWTNativeComponent.java:1006)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.access$17(SWTNativeComponent.java:989)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent$12.run(SWTNativeComponent.java:882)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Native
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**What do I wrong?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JNA example program java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773720/jna-example-program-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: I have add the .jar Files in the folder where my package is, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of the jar files do you use? I can run your code successfully with [DJNativeSwing-SWT-1-0-2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect) (for `DJNativeSwing.jar` and `DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar`) and [swt-4.5-win32-win32-x86_64](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/swt-4.5-win32-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=1186) (for `swt.jar`).

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20441296/1694043) describes a similar scenario and might be useful for you.